# Why do we need to re-build an already built project after copying the project to a new folder?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, ns-3

I had cloned and built a project into a folder. After this I needed to make some changes to it so I copied it to a new directory. Now when I am trying to run this project inside new directory, it is asking to build it again.

Comment: Time stamps of files are used to track whether source code or object files are newer. Location might be considered as well. Which build system do you use?

Comment: using waf build system

Comment: Depends on how you copied the folder, and what OS you're using.   But, in general terms, copying a project probably updates the modification times of some or all files.  One of the criteria used in deciding if recompilation is needed is comparing modification/creation dates of source files and object files (e.g. if the object file is older than the source file, then the source file will be recompiled).

Comment: I am using ubuntu machine. Is this like since all the files and folder get the same timestamp on copying it to a new directory, hence recompilation is needed?

Comment: Why did you copy the project just to make a change? Why not just make the change and then save that in a new commit? To undo the change later you could then just revert the commit or throw it away (if needed) and you'd have a nice way to see exactly what you changed.

Comment: I am new to git and wanted to keep a copy of project in working condition and  make the changes to a new copy. Will try your suggestion onwards.

Comment: Try cp -a <from> <to> syntax. It will recursively copy all the files and preserve attributes, timestamps etc.